# An Introduction to particle acceleration and particle accelerator

Tags: particle-physics, accelerator-physics

I am preparing to write my paper about particle acceleration recently, and i need some general knowledge to get my feet wet about it.
May you please give me an introduction of what particle acceleration is, the concept, the basic mechanism of particle accelerator, the general principle, or please refer me a link of particle acceleration. Thanks!

Regards.

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator. If you have questions about the physics in the Wikipedia article, this might be the place for them, but as it is I think your question is far too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a paper I don't think it makes much sense to try to describe such a general topic here. Instead I can give you a few good references or you might ask more specific questions.

There are two books that are considered in the field to be excellent references:

- [Wiedemann, Particle Accelerator Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540490434)
- [Lee, Accelerator Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812562001)

For a good basic introduction you have the book of Wilson: [An introduction to particle accelerators](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198508298)

You can also have a look at the proceedings of the [CERN Accelerator School (CAS)](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/search?ln=fr&cc=CERN+Yellow+Reports&sc=1&p=CAS&f=&action_search=Recherche). You can search for beginner level, intermediate or advanced. The 2005-004 is a good one to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read this book if you're interested, I think it's great for an introduction:
E. J. N. Wilson, ‘[An introduction to Particle Accelerators](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198508298)’, OXFORD, 2001.